# exclude certain object property in the foreach loop in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkvd9s3x/)

I have a php file to return json data for main content data as well as an additional property for pagaination data. I want to know if it's possible to exclude the property for the pagination data when reiterating over the data in a foreach loop to avoid the undefined warning.

```
var data = [{"larger_than_1":true,"current_page_no":110,"otherpageno":"100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118","current_not_equal_total":"true","nextpage":111,"website":"www.google.com"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},
{"jao":"j","kal":"k"}];
```

The pagination data is always the first property, I tried `if(item[i]!== 0)` but it doesn't work.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "pagination.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {  
      var item_html = "";
      console.log(data[0]);
      item_html += '<h3>'+data[0].larger_than_1+'</h3>';  
      $.each(data,function(index,item)
      {
        if(item[index]!== 0)
        {
          item_html += '<p>'+item.kal+'</p>';
        }

      });
      $('#area').append(item_html);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be just index != 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `item[i]` to `i` in your if statement.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkvd9s3x/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the data which need to be exclude. but as its coming as first value you can simply use index to filter out desired data. i.e. `if(i!= 0)`:

```
var data = [{"larger_than_1":null,"current_page_no":110,"otherpageno":"100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118","current_not_equal_total":"true","nextpage":111,"website":"www.google.com"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"},{"jao":"j","kal":"k"}];
var item_html ="";
jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if(i!= 0)
  {
     item_html += '<p style="margin:5px;background:beige">'+item.kal+'</p>';
  }
  $('#area').append(item_html);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kte1Lqxh/)**